# What MIME for reading .eml file?

Tags: c#, email, imap, mime, eml

I use ImapX library to save email to .eml file. What MIME I can use to read it? MIME can read most of Content-Type.

Comment: Look for them here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 7):

Try to use: "message/rfc822 eml" or "message/rfc822" as Content-type. Maybe it'll work.

Comment: hmm. maybe i understood your question in wrong way. Do you ask what MIME code use to open this email file correctly in browser?

Comment: how to open .eml file in browser?